# Query for many records using "point" data type column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with "location" column which is a PostgreSQL "point" type.

I would like to search for many exact points, something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE location IN ('1,1', '2,2')
```

This doesn't work, it throws an error

> operator does not exist: point = point

To look for exact point one have to use `~=`, but it's only possible to query for one point this way.

I could workaround it, by using `OR`, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE (location ~= '0,1' OR location ~= '1,2')
```

This however looks like not optimal way, as it stops using index (gist) for more than 5 "or"s and do a sequential scan instead.

Is there a way to have a simple and optimal query to get records by looking for exact many points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `any`:

```
WHERE location ~= any (array['1,1'::point, '2,2'::point])
```

I would expect this to use available indexes, but you would have to check on your data.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this is working properly and uses the indexes as well.

Comment: On the sidenote, it is possible to type cast at the end, like `WHERE location ~= any (array['1,1', '2,2']:point[])`